# wcf soap message deserialization error

Tags: wcf, serialization, soap, deserialization

I am getting following error when i make the service call

Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'IbankClientOperation'. OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'doClient_ws_IbankRequest' and namespace 'http://www.informatica.com/wsdl/'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'string' and namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'

i am using following code to call the service

```
    Message requestMsg = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "http://tempuri.org/IService1/IbankClientOperation", requestMessage);

    Message responseMsg = null;

    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    IChannelFactory<IRequestChannel> channelFactory = binding.BuildChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>();
    channelFactory.Open();

    EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(this.Url);
    IRequestChannel channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel(address);
    channel.Open();

    responseMsg = channel.Request(requestMsg);
```

Comment: I think you need to show us your requestMessage parameter being passed to Message.CreateMessage. It seems that your content simply does not conform to the message schema expected at the other end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your requestMessage is the same in [your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6264976) (which seems to be the case, since the error message says it's receiving a string), you're using an incorrect overload of Message.CreateMessage. The one you're using is defined as

```
Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion version, string action, object body);
```

And the "request message" you're passing to it is the whole message envelope. This one you're using will try to serialize the body (and since it's a string, it will serialize it as `<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">...</string>` - which maps exactly to the error message you have.

What you need to use, since you already have the SOAP envelope, is one overload which takes that, such as the one below:

```
Message.CreateMessage(XmlReader enveloperReader, int maxSizeOfHeaders, MessageVersion version);
```

And the code would look something like:

```
string requestMessageString = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:inf="http://www.informatica.com/"
        xmlns:wsdl="http://www.informatica.com/wsdl/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <inf:Security>
            <UsernameToken>
                <Username>john</Username>
                <Password>jhgfsdjgfj</Password>
            </UsernameToken>
        </inf:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <wsdl:doClient_ws_IbankRequest>
            <wsdl:doClient_ws_IbankRequestElement>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <wsdl:Client_No>00460590</wsdl:Client_No>
            </wsdl:doClient_ws_IbankRequestElement>
        </wsdl:doClient_ws_IbankRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";

XmlReader envelopeReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(requestMessageString));
Message requestMsg = Message.CreateMessage(envelopeReader, int.MaxValue, MessageVersion.Soap11);
```

Comment: how do i specify which method to call because this overload of CreateMessage does not have any parameter for action name ..

Comment: Yippee....i got the solution...i added a SOAPAction http header and gave my ActionName as value...Thank You Carlosfigueira :)