# how to send a already constructed SOAP message in WCF

Tags: wcf, serialization, soap, deserialization

I have a SOAP message in a string at my client side

```
string requestMessageString = "<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:inf="http://www.informatica.com/" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://www.informatica.com/wsdl/"> 
    <soapenv:Header> 
       <inf:Security> 
          <UsernameToken> 
             <Username>john</Username> 
             <Password>jhgfsdjgfj</Password> 
          </UsernameToken> 
       </inf:Security> 
    </soapenv:Header> 
    <soapenv:Body> 
       <wsdl:doClient_ws_IbankRequest> 
          <wsdl:doClient_ws_IbankRequestElement> 
             <!--Optional:--> 
             <wsdl:Client_No>00460590</wsdl:Client_No> 
          </wsdl:doClient_ws_IbankRequestElement> 
       </wsdl:doClient_ws_IbankRequest> 
    </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>"
```

and i am sending the message like this

```
Message requestMsg = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "http://tempuri.org/IService1/IbankClientOperation", requestMessageString );

            Message responseMsg = null;

            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            IChannelFactory<IRequestChannel> channelFactory = binding.BuildChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>();
            channelFactory.Open();

            EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(this.Url);
            IRequestChannel channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel(address);
            channel.Open();

            responseMsg = channel.Request(requestMsg);
```

but the problem is that the actual message which is sent over wire has a SOAP message inside a SOAP message...
i somehow want to convert my RAW message into SOAP structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from this question
[wcf soap message deserialization error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263528/wcf-soap-message-deserialization-error)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Soap11` as message version and you cannot use `BasicHttpBinding`. Try:

```
Message requestMsg = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, "http://tempuri.org/IService1/IbankClientOperation", requestMessageString );

CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(new HttpTransportBindingElement());
IChannelFactory<IRequestChannel> channelFactory = binding.BuildChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>();
channelFactory.Open();
```

But anyway if you have SOAP request why don't you simply use `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest` to post the request to the server?

Comment: Thank you :) i found the answer as below

Answer (score 0):

You can convert (deserialize) your SOAP message into an object that your service expects. Here's a sketch of what works for me:

```
var invoice = Deserialize<Invoice>(text);
var result = service.SubmitInvoice(invoice);
```

where Deserialize is this:

```
private T Deserialize<T>(string text)
{
  T obj;
  var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text)))
  {
      obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
  }  
  return obj;
}
```

Since SOAP is XML, you can easily adjust it structure (remove or change namespace, for example) before deserializing.